# Can anyone help me describe the physics of my problem mathematically?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, spring, surface-tension, lattice-model

I was unsure if I should post this here or on the Mathematics page, so I decided to do both. Here's the problem I want to describe: Suppose I have a sphere, discretely represented by a large set of simple planar polygons in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The polygons cover the surface of the sphere and are adjacent to each other with no (or very slight) overlaps between neighbouring polygons. However, the normals of the polygons are the analytical normal of the sphere at the centroid of each polygon, with a perturbation ($<20^{\circ}$) added.

In my actual application (surface tension modelling), the surface can be an arbitrary, smooth, and closed surface. Therefore, unlike for a sphere, I do not know the local surface normal $\textit{a priori}$. I only have the piecewise-linear, polygonal representation of the surface. In order to reduce the perturbations and achieve a smoother distribution of the polygon normals, I want to represent the problem as a set of massless plates allowed to freely pivot about their area centroids, with tensile springs connecting each plate with each of its immediate neighbours. The springs are attached at the edges of each plate.

Can anyone help me describe this problem mathematically, in terms of an objective function that I can numerically minimise? It's important to note that I don't actually intend to simulate the physics of the plate-spring system. I just want to find its lowest energy state, just so I can compute the polygon normals.

$\textit{p.s.}$ I have tried other discrete methods. But there are still large errors in comparison to the analytical normals. My thinking is that the solution to the plate-spring system will yield the most accurate normals I can hope to achieve.

Comment: If you want to simulate surface tension, then there is an equation that describes the surface. Why did you need another equation?

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't have an explicit or implicit equation for the surface. All I have is the discrete representation, from which I infer the surface properties like curvature, normals. The free-surface tracking algorithm that I employ does not maintain an implicit definition of the interface. The free-surface is tracked via a volume-fraction field (liquid-gas ratio in each control volume) on a computational mesh, from which the polygonal representation is reconstructed in a volume-conservative manner.

Comment: What is the name of this method and where is it described?

Comment: Algebraic Volume of Fluid (VOF) method, and it's extensively used in the interfacial flow modelling community..

Comment: OK! Now it’s clear that you want to improve the algorithm for calculating the interface using the physical model. What code do you use?

Comment: That's right! The initial normals are very inacurate because they are inferred from the gradients of the discrete volume fraction field. But because I know that the polygons are constructed conservatively, and because I expect a smootg distrubution of normals/curvature, I can use local neibourhoods of polygons to improve the smoothness. I'm developing an in-house code using C++, so we develop most of the modelling capabilities ourselves.

Comment: Computational Science SE might be more suitable for this question because your goal is to develop a suitable computational algorithm rather than to get a better understanding of the physics of surface tension.

Comment: @niran90 See my answer in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509623/how-to-determine-adhesive-forces-between-fluid-and-a-surface?answertab=active#tab-top  There I used FEM to calculate the surface.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [scicomp.se] or [math.se]

Comment: I foresaw this, so I did not give an answer. Unfortunately, in a physical forum it is impossible to discuss real physical problems.